# No se puede cargar el snap-in de SharePoint en PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Actualmente estoy realizando un script en powershell para agregar unos items a una lista de SharePoint y agregar unas columnas a la misma lista, pero al hacer lo siguiente:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $urlSite, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $urlList)

if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null) 
{ 
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 

Write-Host "Url del Sitio" $urlSite -foregroundcolor yellow

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
   #Aquí algo lo que se requiere hacer....
}
)
```

Me sale el siguiente Error:

> Get-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' were found. Check
>   the pattern and then try the command again.

Es como si no pudiese cargar el ensamblado `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: versión de Sharepoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 Server

Comment: Cómo lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el código solucionado:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $urlSite 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $urlList)

Add-PSSnapin -Name "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "Url del Sitio" $urlSite -foregroundcolor yellow

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
   #Aquí algo lo que se requiere hacer....
}
)
```

Tocaba modificar la sentencia

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null) 
{ 
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
}
```

Por:

```
Add-PSSnapin -Name "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Esto evita que lance un error cuando estoy agregando los ensamblados de SharePoint, al parece cuando ya están cargados lanza un error como si no los tuviera cargados.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno hay que seguir varios pasos, lo primero es asegurarse que la politica de ejecución de scripts es la correcta, y preferiblemente ejecutar esto en una ***consola con privilegios elevados:***

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

En tu caso , puede que exista alguna otra condición que te genere errores, entonces los mejor es cargar el snapin de Sharepoint a lo crudo

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

Y si todo sale bien

```
Get-SPManagedAccount
```

Por supuesto todo esto se debe correr en el Sharepoint server que es donde la dll `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` está instalada en el GAC.

Si lo estás haciendo localmente igual debes asegurarte de tener esa dll en el GAC.

Comment: Tu respuesta es la mas acertada si no tuviera la política de ejecución de escripts, pero en mi caso si la tengo, la solución fe agregar lo siguiente a mi código `Add-PSSnapin -Name "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` el parametro `ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` le dice que si hay error no lo muestre, esto es por que mi código intentaba cargar los ensambaldos de sharepoint, pero cuando ya estaban cargados daba un error como si no los hubiese cargado!. Saludos!